# Tomcat SOLR multiple cores setup

Tags: tomcat, solr, multicore

I have spend all morning trying to set up multiple cores on a SOLR installation that runs under Apache Tomcat server without success. My solr.xml looks like this:

```
<solr persistent="false" sharedLib="lib">
  <cores adminPath="/admin/cores">
    <core name="core0" instanceDir="/multicore/core0">   
        <property name="dataDir" value="/multicore/core0/data" />
    </core>
    <core name="core1" instanceDir="/multicore/core1">
        <property name="dataDir" value="/multicore/core1/data" />
    </core>
  </cores>
</solr>
```

What is the correct directory structure? Do I need to do change something in the solrconfig.xml?

Comment: What version of Tomcat and Apache does it relate to? I'm having a similar problem, but I can't locate these files or configuration settings at all. I'm on Tomcat6, Solr 3.6, Ubuntu.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Check that your instanceDir values are relative to -Dsolr.solr.home. If -Dsolr.solr.home is 'multicore', then your instanceDir should be only "core0".

If you put your data folder inside your instanceDir, you should not have to specify its path:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<solr persistent="true">
<cores adminPath="/admin/cores">
    <core name="core0" instanceDir="core0" />
    <core name="core1" instanceDir="core1" />
</cores>
</solr>
```

You should not have to set anything in solrconfig.xml. But if you need to configure an handler independantly of the core location, you can use the variable ${solr.core.instanceDir}.

**UPDATE**

To set the solr.solr.home variable with Tomcat, use the JAVA_OPTS environment variable before starting Tomcat:

```
JAVA_OPTS="-Dsolr.solr.home=multicore"
export JAVA_OPTS
tomcat/bin/catalina.sh start
```

Make sure that "multicore" is correctly set relative to the working directory. Per example, if solr.solr.home='multicore', you have to launch Tomcat from the directory where "multicore" is located.

Comment: Thanks for the fast answeer Pascal. How can I check what my solr.solr.home is? I'm running solr on Tomcat and not Jetty so cannot set that on the command line when running the start.jar.
I tries the above solr.xml but still get the following error when trying to visit http://devel:12345/solr/core0/admin/

type Status report
message /solr/core0/admin/
description The requested resource (/solr/core0/admin/) is not available.

Any ideas what might be it?

Comment: With Tomcat, you can use the environment variable JAVA_OPTS to set -Dsolr.solr.home before calling the catalina script.

Comment: OK I set the JAVA_OPTS='-Dsolr.solr.home=multicore' but still cannot get it to work. I know that it's a configuration issue but I just can't figure out what I'm missing here.

Comment: @PascalDimassimo What should I do If there are two diffirent versions of Solr?

Answer (score 6):

This is kind of late in the game, but I just put up a blog post with [instructions for a multicore SOLR instance on Tomcat](http://www.plaidpony.com/blog/post/2011/04/Multicore-SOLR-And-Tomcat-On-Windows-Server-2008-R2.aspx) which reads:

> 1. Downloaded and installed the 32-bit/64-bit Windows Service
>      Installer for Tomcat
> 2. Installed Tomcat on the server (no
>      special instructions here--just run the install and install wherever
>      you wish)
> 3. Verified the installation of Tomcat by going to http://localhost:8080
> 4. Edit Tomcat's
>      conf/server.xml and add **URIEncoding="UTF-8"** to the
>      <Connector> element as shown here
> 5. Download
>      SOLR from one of the mirrors found here (downloaded the apache-solr-1.4.1.zip
>      package) and unzip the package
> 6. Create a directory where SOLR
>      will be hosted from (in my case I used e:\inetpub\solr)
> 7. Copy
>      the contents of the **example\solr** directory to your
>      SOLR host directory (in my case e:\inetpub\solr)
> 8. Create
>      directories under your SOLR host directory for each of the cores you
>      wish to create (I created a dozen or so folders for each core I wanted
>      to create in the e:\inetpub\solr directory.  The directories
>      included en-US, en-CA, en-GB, etc.)
> 9. Copy the
>      **solr.xml** file from the
>      **example\multicore** directory and paste it into your
>      SOLR host directory (e:\inetpub\solr for my example)
> 10. Edit
>       the **solr.xml** file to include the information for each
>       of the cores you created (if you created a folder under your host for
>       a core named **en-US**, then add the following under the
>       <cores> element in the **solr.xml** file:
>       **<core name="en-US" instanceDir="en-US" />**)
> 11. Stop the Tomcat Service
> 12. Copy the *solr*.war file from
>       the **dist** directory in the unzipped SOLR package
>       to your Tomcat **webapps** folder
> 13. Rename the
>       *solr*.war file to solr.war
> 14. In the notification area in the right-hand side of the Windows task bar, right-click on the
>       **Apache Tomcat 7** icon and select
>       **Configure**
> 15. Click the **Java**
>       tab and add the following to the **Java Options** text
>       box: **-Dsolr.solr.home=e:\inetpub\solr** (change
>       e:\inetpub\solr to wherever your SOLR is being hosted)
> 16. Click
>       **OK** in the dialog and then start-up the Tomcat
>       service
> 17. Open the **conf\solrconfig.xml** files
>       under each of the cores you created and change the
>       **dataDir** element to point to a specific
>       directory.  If this step is not completed, all of your cores will
>       be using the same data store for their data.
> 18. Stop and
>       re-start the Tomcat Service
> 19. Test that your cores are running
>       by running a query from the web browser http://localhost:8080/solr/en-US/select?q=*:* (replace
>       "en-US" with whatever you've named one of your cores)