# Different Solr Instance with different indexed data?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, solr, solrnet

I'm working on e-Commerce site which is based on ASP.NET MVC3. I've implemented SolrNet 3.6 for improving search.

For that, Only one solr instance is running which is served by Tomcate Apache 7.0 .

My client is demanding  to develop another e-Commerce site using SolrNet which should be by served same Tomcat server.

So is it possible to invoke multiple solr instance having different data?
If yes then How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To do this, you will need to change your setup to have multiple cores. Your Solr install should have an example configuration for this kind of setup under `example/multicore`. In case you can't find it, have a look in [Solr svn repository](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/lucene/dev/tags/lucene_solr_3_6_1/solr/example/multicore/).

See also
 [Tomcat SOLR multiple cores setup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2714046/tomcat-solr-multiple-cores-setup)

Comment: If you follow the guidance outlined by @jpountz, each core will have a separate directory with its own conf and data directory.