# Issue setting up solr multi-core using apache tomcat 7 on windows 8

Tags: solr, tomcat7, apache-zookeeper, solrcloud

I was trying to do multi core setup in `solr` using `apache tomcat 7` on `windows 8`. The solr home opens up , but no cores appear. I checked the logging section and there was the following error:

```
 org.apache.solr.common.SolrException:org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Error Instantiating SearchComponent, solr.clustering.ClusteringComponent failed to instantiate org.apache.solr.handler.component.SearchComponent
```

This is the stack trace when i try to add collection1(default core):

```
SolrCore 'collection1' is not available due to init failure: Error loading class 'solr.clustering.ClusteringComponent',trace=org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: SolrCore 'collection1' is not available due to init failure: Error loading class 'solr.clustering.ClusteringComponent' at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.getCore(CoreContainer.java:785) at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:295) at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:195) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210) at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222) at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123) at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171) at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99) at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953) at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118) at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408) at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1023) at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589) at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(AprEndpoint.java:1852) at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) Caused by: org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Error loading class 'solr.clustering.ClusteringComponent' at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.<init>(SolrCore.java:834) at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.<init>(SolrCore.java:625) at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.createFromLocal(CoreContainer.java:524) at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.create(CoreContainer.java:559) at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer$1.call(CoreContainer.java:249) at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer$1.call(CoreContainer.java:241) at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source) at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source) at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source) ... 3 more Caused by: org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Error loading class 'solr.clustering.ClusteringComponent' at org.apache.solr.core.SolrResourceLoader.findClass(SolrResourceLoader.java:449) at org.apache.solr.core.SolrResourceLoader.findClass(SolrResourceLoader.java:381) at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.createInstance(SolrCore.java:526) at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.createInitInstance(SolrCore.java:582) at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.initPlugins(SolrCore.java:2128) at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.initPlugins(SolrCore.java:2122) at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.initPlugins(SolrCore.java:2155) at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.loadSearchComponents(SolrCore.java:1177) at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.<init>(SolrCore.java:762) ... 11 more Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: solr.clustering.ClusteringComponent at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source) at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source) at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source) at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) at java.net.FactoryURLClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method) at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source) at org.apache.solr.core.SolrResourceLoader.findClass(SolrResourceLoader.java:433) ... 19 more ,code=500}
```

I have already referred [Tomcat SOLR multiple cores setup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2714046/tomcat-solr-multiple-cores-setup) in stackoverflow, but was of no help. also , went through the blogs links given in the post but of no use again.

The stack trace is as follows:

```
org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Error Instantiating SearchComponent, solr.clustering.ClusteringComponent failed to instantiate org.apache.solr.handler.component.SearchComponent
    at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.<init>(SolrCore.java:834)
    at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.<init>(SolrCore.java:625)
    at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.createFromLocal(CoreContainer.java:524)
    at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.create(CoreContainer.java:559)
    at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer$1.call(CoreContainer.java:249)
    at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer$1.call(CoreContainer.java:241)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Error Instantiating SearchComponent, solr.clustering.ClusteringComponent failed to instantiate org.apache.solr.handler.component.SearchComponent
    at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.createInstance(SolrCore.java:547)
    at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.createInitInstance(SolrCore.java:582)
    at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.initPlugins(SolrCore.java:2128)
    at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.initPlugins(SolrCore.java:2122)
    at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.initPlugins(SolrCore.java:2155)
    at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.loadSearchComponents(SolrCore.java:1177)
    at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.<init>(SolrCore.java:762)
    ... 11 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: class org.apache.solr.handler.clustering.ClusteringComponent
    at java.lang.Class.asSubclass(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.solr.core.SolrResourceLoader.findClass(SolrResourceLoader.java:443)
    at org.apache.solr.core.SolrResourceLoader.findClass(SolrResourceLoader.java:381)
    at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.createInstance(SolrCore.java:526)
```

**Here is my Solr.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!--
 Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one or more
 contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file distributed with
 this work for additional information regarding copyright ownership.
 The ASF licenses this file to You under the Apache License, Version 2.0
 (the "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance with
 the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at

     http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

 Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 limitations under the License.
-->

<!--
 All (relative) paths are relative to the installation path

  persistent: Save changes made via the API to this file
  sharedLib: path to a lib directory that will be shared across all cores
-->
<solr persistent="true">

  <!--
  adminPath: RequestHandler path to manage cores.  
    If 'null' (or absent), cores will not be manageable via request handler
  -->
  <cores adminPath="/admin/cores">
    <core name="core0" instanceDir="core0"/>
    <core name="core1" instanceDir="core1"/>
    <!--<core name="collection1" instanceDir="collection1"/>-->
  </cores> 
</solr>
```

**Updated question :**
   **solrconfig.xml**

```
<lib dir="C:/Users/admin/Desktop/solr/solr-4.5.0/solr-4.5.0/contrib/extraction/lib" regex=".*\.jar" />
 <lib dir="C:/Users/admin/Desktop/solr/solr-4.5.0/solr-4.5.0/dist/" regex="solr-cell-\d.*\.jar" />

 <lib dir="C:/Users/admin/Desktop/solr/solr-4.5.0/solr-4.5.0/contrib/clustering/lib/" regex=".*\.jar" />
 <lib dir="C:/Users/admin/Desktop/solr/solr-4.5.0/solr-4.5.0/dist/" regex="solr-clustering-\d.*\.jar" />

 <lib dir="C:/Users/admin/Desktop/solr/solr-4.5.0/solr-4.5.0/contrib/langid/lib/" regex=".*\.jar" />
 <lib dir="C:/Users/admin/Desktop/solr/solr-4.5.0/solr-4.5.0/dist/" regex="solr-langid-\d.*\.jar" />

 <lib dir="C:/Users/admin/Desktop/solr/solr-4.5.0/solr-4.5.0/contrib/velocity/lib" regex=".*\.jar" />
 <lib dir="C:/Users/admin/Desktop/solr/solr-4.5.0/solr-4.5.0/dist/" regex="solr-velocity-\d.*\.jar" />
```

Comment: Hello @Naresh , I am facing the same issue , Did you able to figure it out ?

Answer (score 0):

ClusteringComponent is a contribution to SOLR, not a core component.
Therefore you need to add its binaries/dependencies somewhere on the class path.
The easiest way is to define it inside the solrconfig.xml - there you can specifically point on directory/jar etc.

Comment: I have already added the definition of the clustering component in solrconfig.xml as updated in the question:

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you are pointing to your right collection1 folder which contains the conf solrconfig.xml where you added some modifications for lib ?

What did you put in the key "solr/home" of the web.xml (solr.war) ?
The value must be the directory of your solr home, just under this directory you must have bin and collection1 directory..the one which contains the file solorconfig.xml..

```
<env-entry>
       <env-entry-name>solr/home</env-entry-name>
       <env-entry-value>\solr_home</env-entry-value>
       <env-entry-type>java.lang.String</env-entry-type>
</env-entry>
```